# Create threads for scanning directory

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, nas

So I have a large directory tree (20k+ folders) I'd like to scan for certain files. The directory has several deep paths that can take a while to traverse. Doing os.walk takes about 6 mins and I'm wondering if there's a way to speed this up.

I'd like to feed the script the top folder and have it work through the sub-folders spawning threads as it needs. For instance, feeding it "\top" would instruct it to spawn threads for the folders directly under "\top". Next it would spawn threads for all the folders under "\top\a". As this progressed it would lead to a large number of threads being created so limiting this would be preferred. As the threads in folder "\top\a" complete they would allow threads in say folder "\top\d" to begin.

The end goal would be to run this script regularly to update it with new files as they are found.

Comment: Might not speed anything up depending on the File IO. Are concurrent disk reads possible on your environment?

Comment: @flakes I believe so as this is a large NAS appliance connected to a cluster.

Comment: Might be better asked on the superuser stack exchange where the answer is most likely language agnostic. You will want to include info about the storage system setup and your program's environment.

Comment: @flakes I could test and compare against a basic os.walk 4-5 line function if I knew how to create this sort of approach.

Comment: Try splitting the top level directories into `n` somewhat even chunks. Start `n` threads and pass one chunk to each thread to start walking. See the following for a threading example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm